# FactoryGirl/Rails: replace existing method called from module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, module, factory-bot

I have several classes that include a module `EventTracker`, which in turn uses callbacks to record events. EventTracker calls `my_config` in each class, which returns a Hash which is populated with names of fields to ignore in the event tracking process.

```
require 'event_tracker'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    EVENTS = Rails.application.config_for(:users)

    include EventTracker    

    def my_config
        EVENTS
    end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

Here's the module:

```
module EventTracker

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save :record_event
    after_destroy :record_destroyed
  end

    def get_change_fields
        attribute_names - my_config['exclude']
    end

    private

        def record_event
            changed = {}
            puts "my config is #{my_config}"
            self::changes.each do |key, val|
                changed[key] = val if get_change_fields().include? key
            end
            Event.record_event self, changed
        end

        def record_destroyed
            Event.record_event self, nil, 'destroy'
        end

end
```

This works fine in the console and running on the server, but when I try to run RSpec tests, which have to create a user to login with, I get an error when the user is created: the method `get_change_fields` fails when it calls `my_config` in the instance. I imagine this is because the class hasn't loaded and parsed the yaml file that contains the needed data?

```
Failures:

  1) CasesController should have a current_user
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of nil into Array
     # ./app/models/event_tracker.rb:11:in `-'
     # ./app/models/event_tracker.rb:11:in `get_change_fields'
     # ./app/models/event_tracker.rb:20:in `block in record_event'
     # ./app/models/event_tracker.rb:19:in `each'
```

Is there a way to get FactoryGirl to step in and provide a Hash value when `my_config` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
    let(:my_config) { exclude: 'exclude' }

    before do
      allow(subject).to receive_messages(my_config: my_config)
    end
```

You can stub `my_config` for your current user in RSpec test like I showed you above. 
Let me know if that works. I can update the answer seeing your output.

Comment: not sure this is going in the right direction... throwing an error:

cases_controller_spec.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
 let(:my_config) { exclude: 'exclude' }

But this is a case where a class and a module call back and forth to each other, and so I imagine it's outside of the scope of FactoryGirl. What I'm going to try doing is changing the structure so that the EventTracker grabs the yaml file that the data comes from, reducing a second-order dependency...

Comment: Could you use: 
let(:my_config) { 'exclude': 'exclude' }
I did not test the above code. But this should fix the current error.
Basically, what you need to do is to mock your my_config in RSpec.
How does your my_config yaml file look like?